# MYSQL migrating to postgreSQL issues

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Trying to convert my MYSQL db to postgreSQL so it will play nicely with heroku. I installed the gem mysql2psql and run it. When I run it, I get...

```
mysql2psql
Creating table breads...
Created table breads
Creating table sammiches...
Created table sammiches
Creating table schema_migrations...
Created table schema_migrations
Counting rows of breads... 
Rows counted
Loading breads...

33 rows loaded in 0min 0s
Counting rows of sammiches... 
Rows counted
Loading sammiches...

161 rows loaded in 0min 0s
Counting rows of schema_migrations... 
Rows counted
Loading schema_migrations...

4 rows loaded in 0min 0s
Indexing table breads...
Indexed table breads
Indexing table sammiches...
Indexed table sammiches
Indexing table schema_migrations...
Indexed table schema_migrations
Table creation 0 min, loading 0 min, indexing 0 min, total 0 min
```

if I am in pg:psql I can run queries and I know that the columns imported correctly to the table, but there are no entries...

I tried-

```
heroku rake db:migrate
WARNING: `heroku rake` has been deprecated. Please use `heroku run rake` instead.
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.6669
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:7)
Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
Migrating to CreateSammiches (20130428211616)
```

But it is still empty. Empty likeeeee

```
dbl77pdgmr9l10=> select * from sammiches;                                                                                                                        id | name | image | country | description | created_at | updated_at 
----+------+-------+---------+-------------+------------+------------
(0 rows)

dbl77pdgmr9l10=>
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

mysql2psql file-

```
mysql:
 hostname: localhost
 port: 3306
 socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
 username: root
 password: ####
 database: sandwich_development

destination:
 # if file is given, output goes to file, else postgres
 file: 
 postgres:
  hostname: localhost
  port: 5432
  username: root
  password: 
  database: pgmysql_db

# if tables is given, only the listed tables will be converted.  leave empty to convert all tables.
#tables:
#- table1
#- table2
# if exclude_tables is given, exclude the listed tables from the conversion.
#exclude_tables:
#- table3
#- table4


# if supress_data is true, only the schema definition will be exported/migrated, and not the data
supress_data: false

# if supress_ddl is true, only the data will be exported/imported, and not the schema
supress_ddl: false

# if force_truncate is true, forces a table truncate before table loading
force_truncate: false
```

Comment: If you know the data structure, what is to stop you writing your own convertor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your database.yaml configuration

```
suppress_data: true
```

Might be not moving data, only schema

Comment: Hmm, it is set to false. Thanks!

Comment: I added the mysqlpsql yml file.

Comment: try dumping to file to see if insert statements for existing data are present, rather than straight to postgres

Comment: Hmm, the file dump has all the information. I am wondering if it is an issue with the formatting of the content? Like one of my entries looks like 135 Smörgåstårta //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/a/a7/Sm%C3%B6rg%C3%A5st%C3%A5rta.jpg/120px-Sm%C3%B6rg%C3%A5st%C3%A5rta.jpg Sweden Multiple layers of white or light rye bread containing creamy fillings, such as egg and mayonnaise, liver paté, olives, shrimp, ham, various cold cuts, caviar, tomato, cucumber, cheese and smoked salmon 2013-05-09 22:11:37 2013-05-09 22:11:37

Comment: now try running those dump files into mysql from command line and see if you get any errors?